# What styles does ActionBarSherlock transfer to previous Android versions?

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

If I'm using ActionBarSherlock, and My activity looks like this in Ice Cream Sandwich:

[image]

will the buttons and other elements keep Ice Cream Sandwich's style or will they revert to the Android version It's running on? (If I'm running it on 2.3, will the buttons look like standard Android 2.3 buttons, or will they still look like Android 4.0 like the picture?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock does nothing to backport any style other than that of the action bar. The only reason that it does this is to create a consistent base for styling.

Bringing back anything else would be out-of-scope for the library. Your buttons will look like gingerbread buttons on pre-Honeycomb Android. I strongly suggest you take the assets from the platform you like (such as Ice Cream Sandwich) and customize them to fit your app's look and feel and then use those on every platform.